# on keydown capture is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I want to capture Enter key press when `startSkipMenu()` initiated, but it doesn't work for some reason

```js
let onSkipedMenuKeydown;

function startSkipMenu() { 
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onSkipedMenuKeydown);
  onSkipedMenuKeydown = function (event) {    
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          console.log('Enter key pressed');
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  }
}

startSkipMenu();
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to define the content of `onSkipedMenuKeydown` before adding event listener.

```js
let onSkipedMenuKeydown;

function startSkipMenu() {
  onSkipedMenuKeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('Enter key pressed');
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onSkipedMenuKeydown);
}

startSkipMenu();
```